# creating a dynamic ul using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a `li` item and append the fragment dynamically to `ul` using only javascript. it is part of a project. I have written a code but every time the console is giving me a different error, the last one was "document is not defined". I need to know what I am doing wrong.
the errors I get on the console was:
1- getAttribute is not a function.
2-document is not defined
3- appendChild is not a function.
4- cannot appendChild to null

```
const nav_list= document.querySelectorAll("section");
const myUl = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
   // create fragment
let nav_fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
 
function addItemList(){
    for (let i = 0; i < nav_list.length; i++){
        let newText= nav_list[i].getAttribute("data-nav");
        // creat new li
        let newLi= documnet.creatElement("li");
        // create new link
        let newLink= document.createElement ("a");
        // create text node
        let textNode = document.creatTextNode ("newText");

        // add eventListener
        newLink.addEventListener("click", function(){
            section[i].scrollIntoView({behavior : "smooth"});
        });
        newLink.appendChild(textNode);
        newLi.appendChild(newLink);
        nav_fragment.appendChild(newLi);      
  
    }
    myUl.appendChild(nav_fragment);
}
// Build menu
addItemList();
```

** edit: the script tag is added at the bottom of the html right before the .

Comment: are you adding the script to head section? if yes, try adding it before closing </body>, also you can use `window.addEventListener('load', function() { /* Your_Code_here*/ } , false);` as a wrapper for your code to make sure that the document is ready, also try to edit your question and mention the other errors you get

Comment: the script is added at the bottom of the html right before the </html> tag. so the document should be loaded by then, I added the errors I had.

Comment: typo: `documnet`

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that the document is loaded, add your script in a function called when the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event is triggered.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
... your code here
});
```